# Is it possible to change a web reference URL at compile time

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-services, cruisecontrol.net

We currently have an application that uses a web service. The web service URL is different for our DEV, UAT and LIVE environments as the web services talk to different databases (I didn't design it this way).

I would like to be able to build all three versions from the one source code base. At the moment, I need to manually edit the web reference URL in Visual Studio. What would be good is to somehow specify the web reference URL at compile time. I'm thinking that maybe I could use a pre-build hook or something to change the web reference URL, but not sure how I would do this, assuming it was possible.

Our builds are triggered from CruiseControl.NET just to give you the overall picture.

Answer (score 1):

Could you do this with different build configurations?

I don't have an example with a web reference handy right now, but it'll be in the .csproj file. You can conditionally include notes in the csproj file using syntax like this:

```
  <Choose>
    <When Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='Release' ">

         <!-- add the reference, web reference etc node here -->

    </When>
  </Choose>
```

You'd have to edit your .csproj file manually to do this

Comment: That's a pretty neat suggestion. I'll have a look into that as it may be what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Why do this when you can get Visual Studio to make the config transforms for you?

Comment: How do I get Visual Studio to make these config changes?

Comment: @DomBurf Are you making Windows application or website?

Comment: It's actually an Android application using the Xamarin.Android plug-in for Visual Studio.

Comment: @DomBurf I'm not too familiar with that (something on my list to learn!), how are you keeping your configuration settings? Are they in an `app.config` file?

Comment: The application doesn't currently use an app.config, but this problem has made me consider using one. How would I read the values from it at compile time though?

Answer (score 0):

How are you triggering these builds? Force. Change url. Force. Change url. Force? If so use a cruisecontrol parameter to choose what url you want. Send that choice to whatever build task you're using like Nant for example. In Nant, edit the code file with the desired url and build. You'd have to do some file editing from Nant to change the url.

If you want all three builds every time then you don't need the parameter. The first build would trigger the other two and the different urls would be hard coded somewhere in your build task.

I've used C# script in Nant before to edit a file for a specific build flavor.